# Flutter: how to create a dotted border with custom radius?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i create a dotted border in flutter with radius on only top side of the border using the package `dotted_border`

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom path property in the `dotted_border` package or use custom painter to draw the shape.

Eg for custom path to add border just on the top side:

```
DottedBorder(
   customPath: (Size size) {
     double radius = 10;
     return Path()..moveTo(0, radius)
     ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2), math.pi, math.pi/2, true)
     .lineTo(size.width - radius, 0)
     ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - radius * 2, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2), -math.pi/2, math.pi/2, true)
     ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
     ..lineTo(0, size.height)
     ..lineTo(0, radius);
   },
   child: _yourChild
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package [dotted_border](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border) to achieve your goal.

Example

```
return DottedBorder(
  borderType: BorderType.RRect,
  radius: Radius.circular(12),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.only(topLeft:Radius.circular(40))),
    child: Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 120,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  ),
);
```